# MySQL syntax error I don't understand

Tags: mysql

MySQL generated by a dump of a v3.23.58 database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article`;
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `DATE` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `SECTION_ID` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `PRIORITY` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR1` int(100) NOT NULL default '1',
  `AUTHOR2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR3` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR4` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR5` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR6` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR7` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR8` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR9` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR10` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR_JOB` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `TITLE` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `SUBHEAD` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `TEXT` text NOT NULL,
  `PULLQUOTE` text NOT NULL,
  `SERIES` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `TYPE` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `VIEWS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `EMAILS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `BACKUPTEXT` text NOT NULL,
  `BOWDOIN_VIEWS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`DATE`,`SECTION_ID`,`PRIORITY`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `article_full_text` (`TITLE`,`TEXT`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Attempting to import it into a v5.5.19 database, I get this error:

```
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 28
```

I've tried deconstructing it to a very basis skeleton but still get the error. Ought to be an obvious mistake if you have the eye for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of MySQL probably requires that you edit  query

replace

```
TYPE=MyISAM
```

with

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

if you are importing from script file then just:

1. Open script file
2. Find TYPE=MyISAM
3. Replace with ENGINE=MyISAM
4. save

Then try .

Answer (score 3):

change last line

```
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

to

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

so all would be

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article`;
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `DATE` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `SECTION_ID` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `PRIORITY` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR1` int(100) NOT NULL default '1',
  `AUTHOR2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR3` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR4` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR5` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `AUTHOR6` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR7` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR8` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR9` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR10` int(100) NOT NULL default '0',
  `AUTHOR_JOB` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `TITLE` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `SUBHEAD` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `TEXT` text NOT NULL,
  `PULLQUOTE` text NOT NULL,
  `SERIES` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `TYPE` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `VIEWS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `EMAILS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  `BACKUPTEXT` text NOT NULL,
  `BOWDOIN_VIEWS` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '0000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`DATE`,`SECTION_ID`,`PRIORITY`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `article_full_text` (`TITLE`,`TEXT`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```